# How does QT display minority language strings as they are

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding

I am using QT creator writing a program (under Windows) to read the string in the text file. There is a string in Spanish: `explosión demográfica`, in which there are letters like `ó`. The QT program won't show it on the label correctly.

I used tr() directly, but it didn't help. Neither QString::toutf8(). I also want to use this string as the file name of the production file in windows system, but it is garbled.

Please help me! I wonder how to show it correctly?

Here is some codes:

```
emit sendWaitingMsg(tr("Creating CASE1-%1.txt...").arg(m_gameName));
```

This is a signal to tell what's going on now.

`m_gameName` stores the string `EXPLOSIÓN`.

The signal send this message and then the GUI shows it on a label.

And this is how I read strings from an .txt file:

```
QTextStream stmIn(&file);
QString line = stmIn.readLine().trimmed();
m_gameName = line;
```

`EXPLOSI脫N.txt` This is the garbled display. By the way, the file uses UTF-8 encoding.
(sorry I can not upload a picture.)

Thanks a lot.

Alright, I have solved this problem just now unexpectedly by using `m_gameName.toLocal8Bit().data()`,  and it is the same whether use tr() or not.

Many thanks to everybody!

Comment: What you are referring to is Unicode.  Qt has good support Unicode.  One of the more common mistakes is hardcoding unicode characters into ascii source files without an understanding of encoding, utf-8 vs utf-16, etc.... Can you share your code ala [mcve] ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64747574/edit) any clarifications into your question, code is hard to read in the comments

Comment: Open the file in Notepad.  Save it back as UTF-8.  Skip the tr function.  If that doesn't work, explain what you mean by "garbled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this extraordinary [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:

- `Ó` *Latin Capital Letter O With Acute*  (Unicode `U+00D3`, utf-8 byte sequence `0xC3`, `0x93`)
- `脫` *CJK Unified Ideograph* (GBK `C393`)
- `脫` *CJK Ideograph-812B* (Unicode `U+812B`)

The [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) mechanism is self-explained in the following Python script:

```
print( 'Ó  ->', 'Ó'.encode('utf-8').hex(), '(UTF-8)')
print( '脫 ->', '脫'.encode('gbk').hex(), '(GBK)')
print( 'Ó  ->', 'Ó'.encode('utf-8').
                    decode('gbk').
                    encode('utf-16BE').hex(), '(utf-8 → gbk → Unicode)')
print( 'Ó  ->', 'Ó'.encode('utf-8').
                    decode('gb18030').
                    encode('utf-16BE').hex(), '(utf-8 → gb18030 → Unicode)')
print( '脫 ->', '脫'.encode('utf-16BE').hex(), '(Unicode)')
```

**Output**: `64747574.py`

```
Ó  -> c393 (UTF-8)
脫 -> c393 (GBK)
Ó  -> 812b (utf-8 → gbk → Unicode)
Ó  -> 812b (utf-8 → gb18030 → Unicode)
脫 -> 812b (Unicode)
```